# EMF Compare programatically for local history of uml file

Tags: java, emf-compare

I am trying to compare a uml file with its local history. Is it possible to do it programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you will have to find the proper history revision to compare with yourself.

See `org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.getHistory(IProgressMonitor)` for info on how to retrieve the local history of a given file. You will then need to load these revisions as EMF Resources for use by EMF Compare.

Something like the following should get you started:

```
String uri = "platform:/resource/project/path/to/file.ext";
IFile file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(new Path(uri));
IFileState[] states = file.getHistory(new NullProgressMonitor());
if (states.length > 0) {
    IFileState lastFromHistory = states[0];
    ResourceSet set = new ResourceSetImpl();
    Resource res = set.createResource(URI.createURI(uri));
    res.load(lastFromHistory.getContents(), Collections.emptyMap());
}
```